# Application icon always in foreground

Tags: android, android-activity, foreground

I have an app where i start a service. When start Service is activated,
I want an icon in the home page and where ever the user navigates that icon should be present. On clicking on the icon, certain functions should be performed. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know basically your service is running or not from you home screen, then put a static boolean field in your service, mark this field as true onstart of service and false ondestroy.

Now you have a flag basically, you can access this field statically to check whether its running or not from any where in your app.

I hope got your problem right.